# Google Fit DataUpdateListener callback not called

Tags: android, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

I'm trying to follow [this guide](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/listen-for-data) to add a `DataUpdateListener` to listen for `DataType.TYPE_WEIGHT` events like so:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, FitnessStoreUpdatesReceiver.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
Fitness.HistoryApi.registerDataUpdateListener(googleApiClient,
            new DataUpdateListenerRegistrationRequest.Builder()
                    .setDataType(DataType.TYPE_WEIGHT)
                    .setPendingIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .build());
```

My `FitnessStoreUpdatesReceiver` is identical to the one linked in the guide. However, adding a weight event through the Google Fit Android app does not trigger my listener. Have I missed something in my implementation?

Comment: Hi, did you solve? Link is broken now.

Comment: How did you solve this issue?

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue?

Comment: I never solved this issue, sorry.